# Softlayer : Failed to place an order for Public Virtual Server using Softlayer API

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Can some one from IBM-Softlayer team help me out in resolving the ISSUE,
I tried to place an Order for "Public Virtual Server" by calling Softlayer API as below. But got this response:

```
{"error":"Could not place order. An uncaught exception was encountered. Please contact Sales.","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}
```

API URL :

```
https://<<API_Username>>:<<API_Key>>@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/
```

request body json:

```
{
  "parameters":[
    {
      "hostname":"stack-teste-daniel-20180720",
      "domain":"stack-teste-daniel-20180720.com",
      "startCpus":2,
      "maxMemory":1024,
      "hourlyBillingFlag":true,
      "localDiskFlag":true,
      "operatingSystemReferenceCode":"CENTOS_7_64",
      "datacenter":{"name":"ams01"},
      "blockDevices":[{"device":"0","diskImage":{"capacity":25}}]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your request and it is working for me, your issue is with some restriction on your account I recommend you to contact softlayer sales for further help.

Comment: F.Ojeda thanks for the replay, I retired and worked for me also.